# How do we get from one fromula to another?

Tags: linear-algebra

My question is about the projection. The projection onto a hyperplane defined by $$H:=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=b\}$$ is defined by $$P_{H}(x)=x-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle-b}{||a||^2}a\dots\dots(1).$$Also when this hyperplane passes through the origin then we will have a subspace$$S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n:\langle a,x\rangle=0\}$$and the projection can be defined by $$P_{S}(x)=x-\frac{\langle a,x\rangle}{||a||^2}a\dots\dots(2).$$Now for any subspace $V$ (not necessary to be a hyperplane) if we construct a matrix $A$ whose columns consists of linearly independents spanning set for $V$ then the projection can be defined by $$P_V(x)=A(A^TA)^{-1}A^T(x)\dots\dots(3).$$My question is how do we get from $(3) $ to $(2)$? Can anyone show that to me? I know that the hyperplane $H$ and the subspace $S$ are of dimension $n-1$and I can understand how do we get $(1)$ and $(2)$ but not able to make an argument about how do we get$(1)$ from $(3)$.I will be great full for any explanation or proof.

Answer (score 1):

Let me rephrase your question a little bit.

We are given a matrix $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times (n-1)}$ with $rank\ B = n-1.$ Then the columns of $B$ are linearly independent and form the basis of a linear hyperplane $S := B \mathbb R^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb R^n.$ The orthogonal projection onto $S$ is described by $y = B(B^TB)^{-1}B^Tx$ for $x\in\mathbb R^n.$ For future reference, we put $$
P := B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.
$$

We also have the "dual" description of $S,$ namely there is a vector $a \in\mathbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $S = \{x \in \mathbb R^n|a^Tx = 0\}.$ With this data, the orthogonal projection onto $S$ is described by $y = x - \frac{a^Tx}{a^Ta}a.$ Note that $a^Tx \in \mathbb R,$ and thus $(a^Tx)a = a(a^Tx) = (aa^T)x.$ Here, note that $aa^T \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.$ We can use this to rewrite
$$
\begin{align}
y & = x - \frac{a^Tx}{a^Ta}a \\
& = x - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}x \\
& = (I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta})x,
\end{align}
$$
where $I \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ denotes the identity matrix. Let's put
$$
Q := \left(I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}\right) \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}.
$$

With all these preparations, we want to show $P = Q.$ This can be done as follows. Since the columns of $B$ are elements of $S,$ we have
$$
a^TB = 0.
$$
This implies that $a$ and the columns of $B$ are linearly independent. Thus, the matrix
$$
U := (a\ B) \subseteq \mathbb R^{n\times n}
$$
has rank $n$ and is invertible. Then, also its transpose
$$
U^T = {a^T\choose B^T}
$$
is invertible. With that, we have
$$
P = Q\qquad iff \qquad U^TP = U^TQ.
$$
Now we calculate (observing  that $a^TB = 0$ is equivalent to $B^Ta = 0$)
$$
\begin{align}
U^TP & = {a^T\choose B^T}B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T \\
& = {a^TB(B^TB)^{-1}B^T\choose B^TB(B^TB)^{-1}B^T} \\
& = {(a^TB)(B^TB)^{-1}B^T\choose (B^TB)(B^TB)^{-1}B^T} \\
& = {0\choose B^T}, \\
\end{align}
$$
since $a^TB = 0,$ and moreover
$$
\begin{align}
U^TQ & = {a^T\choose B^T}\left(I - \frac{aa^T}{a^Ta}\right) \\
& = {a^T\choose B^T} - {\frac{a^Taa^T}{a^Ta}\choose\frac{B^Taa^T}{a^Ta}} \\
& = {a^T\choose B^T} - {\frac{(a^Ta)a^T}{a^Ta}\choose\frac{(B^Ta)a^T}{a^Ta}} \\
& = {a^T\choose B^T} - {a^T\choose 0} \\
& = {0\choose B^T},
\end{align}
$$
since $B^Ta = 0.$
So we have indeed $P = Q,$ as desired.

Comment: Big big thanks to you Jflipp for this explanation but I just did not understand the first two statement, that is why $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times n-1}$ with $rank\ B = n-1.$" and how is $S := B \mathbb R^{n-1} \subseteq \mathbb R^n.$? Could you please make it more clear? Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Of course, I mean $B \in \mathbb R^{n\times(n-1)}.$ In your question, you have the linear subspace $V$ and construct from this the matrix $A$ whose columns are a basis of $V.$ Your matrix $A$ is my matrix $B.$ And $V$ is a linear hyperplane (i.e. contains $0$) iff $rank\ B = n-1.$ If $V$ is not a hyperplane, then we can't construct the projection $P_S$ from your question, and your question becomes meaningless.

Comment: Regarding $S = B\mathbb R^{n-1}.$ $S$ is spanned by the columns of $B.$ If we consider $\mathbb R^{n-1}$ as the set of all column vectors of dimension $n-1,$ then the span of the columns of $B$ is exactly $B\mathbb R^{n-1} = B\{v|v\in\mathbb R^{n-1}\} = \{Bv|v \in \mathbb R^{n-1}\}.$

Comment: Thanks again. I have another question which is related to the above if you are happy to give more help, please do. The question is if we have a subspace (affine subspace) which is the intersection of hyperplanes, how can we derive the projection formula for projection onto that affine subspace? In other words how to link between the alternating projections, the projection onto hyperplanes, and the projection onto affine subspace? Thanks.

Comment: @rinanyosf: better to ask a new question.